# Query to get the data between two dates with only specific time duraion

Tags: db2

I want to pull data from DB2 from 01-June-2016 to 30-June-2016 from 5 PM to 6 PM only. Can anyone please help me how to achieve this?

`CRTN_TS` type is `Timetamp` format of DB2.

I tried using below query, but gives all values between 20160601220000000000 and 20160601230000000000.

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
WHERE CRTN_TS >= TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('20160601220000000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF6') 
  AND CRTN_TS <= TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('20160601230000000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF6')
```

Comment: If one of the answers works for you, please marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

To get only records created between 5pm and 6pm any day June 2016..

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
WHERE date(CRTN_TS) between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-30'
     and time(CRTN_TS) between '17:00:00' and '18:00:00'
```

Comment: @JayShukla, glad to know.  Please mark the answer as accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Using ISO format should work

```
 where crtn_ts >= '2016-06-01-22.00.00.000000'
   and crtn_ts <= '2016-06-01-23.00.00.000000'
```

alternatively you could cast it as timestamp

```
 where crtn_ts >= timestamp('2016-06-01-22.00.00.000000')
   and crtn_ts <= timestamp('2016-06-01-23.00.00.000000')
```